# gmaps.js add marker from PHP array

Tags: php, jquery, gmaps.js

I am trying to add a marker to my gmaps.js map. The long. and lat. values are stored in a database, which I select using a PHP Script.

Once fetched, both of the long. and lat. values are stored in an array, under the variable $data.

I wanted to use json_encode($data); in order to pass the variables, however I would have had to change the header to a json application, I have already echoed some PHP onto the page, therefore this is unfeasable.

I have now tried echoing the json_encode into the jQuery function using an $.each loop, however it has been unsuccessful, as not every entry retrieved by the database will have a marker.

What is the best solution, to get an ID, long. and lat. value for max 10 records, pass this to a jQuery function to position on a map?

Comment: use ajax to fetch the markers or assign as a js variable when the page loads

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have tweaked your post for clarity.  It might help if you posted your current effort for others to inspect.

Answer (score 0):

As not all records have markers, youll have to parse the results so that only the required data gets passed to your js function. I'd create a php array and add the marker I'd, lat,long etc... Under the same key:

```
$markersarray = array ()
foreach($records as $record){

  if($record['lat'] != ““){
    $markersarray[] = array(
         'id'=>$record['id'], 
         'lat'=>$record['lat'],
         'long'=>$record['long']
    );
  }
}

$markersjson = json_encode($markersarray);
```

Then you could use a hidden input to store the encoded json string which then could be passed into your js.

```
 <input id="markersjson" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $markersjson; ?>"/>
```

in your js function

```
var markersdata = $('#markersjson').val();
```

You may need to parse this value to an object

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(markersdata);
```

then use a $.each to loop through your obj